# Form helper of "select" renders the empty option wihout text in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this `select` helper:

```
= form.select(:door, options_for_select(Door.variants), {}, style: "width: 100%", required: true, prompt: "select me")
```

It renders the following HTML:

```
<select style="width: 100%" required="required" prompt="select it" name="door" id="door" class="error">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="var1">var1</option>
  <option value="var2">var2</option>
</select>
```

But why doesn't it have the text for the empty value? How do I fix this?

Comment: What is `Door.variants` returning?

Comment: You are passing `prompt: 'select me'` as an html option (check it's rendered as an attribute of the select tag), move it inside that empty `{}` where the helper options go.

Comment: @arieljuod thx.

Comment: @Joddari if you've solved this problem, please post an answer here for the community.